# Make a 3ds max file unviewable

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I want to make a 3ds max file (.max) unviewable but still be able to render it.

Is there any maxscript snippet to help or is it even possible?

I am looking for any type of encryption or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, 20+ years in 3ds Max, there is no way to have a encrypted renderable scene.  You could put in a persistent postOpen callback to turn off the viewports and command panel. This is typically done to improve script run time speed, but this would fool most users into believing the file is locked by magic somehow.

Enter this line below in your listener to add the callbacks to your FILE.  This will remain in the file. You don't want to do this to your production file, just the one you are sending somewhere I presume.

```
callbacks.addScript #filePostOpen "disableSceneRedraw();suspendEditing()" persistent:true
```

When the file opens the viewports should appear empty ( they might show the scene, I've not tested this ) and the command panel will be non-interactive.

Every time you open the file you will need to enable scene redraw and command panel with the following commands in the listener.

enableSceneRedraw();resumeEditing()

An experienced 3ds Max user may see through this hack.

https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_52E2EA19_D42C_4240_A061_CB0DC364267E_htm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).